# How to make all rows have same size?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I'm new in openxml and I am trying to learn basics. I have been trying to create tables with different properties but couldn't pass an issue. I need to make all rows have same width in the table ignoring column counts they have.
This is my code:

```
 public static Table createTable(String[][] data)
     {
         Table table = new Table();

         table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(createTableProps());
         for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
         {
             var tr = new TableRow();
             for (var j = 0; j < data[i].Length; j++)
             {
                 int size = 1200 / data[i].Length;
                 var tc = new TableCell();

                 tc.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = size.ToString()}));


                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(runTools.getRun(16, "Tahoma", new Text(data[i][j])));

                 tc.Append(para);

                 // Assume you want columns that are automatically sized.
                /* TableCellWidth tcw = new TableCellWidth{Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Auto };
                 tcw.Width = new StringValue("500");
                 tc.Append(new TableCellProperties(tcw));*/

                 tr.Append(tc);
             }
             table.Append(tr);
         }
         return table;
     }
```

This is what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `GridSpan` to your top column in order for it to span across 2 columns. Adjusting the width of your column won't work as a cell can't be wider than the rest of the column.

From the [documentation for GridSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.gridspan%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

> This property allows cells to have the appearance of being merged, as they span vertical boundaries of other cells in the table

In your code you could add a check for `data[i].Length == 1` - if it is then you can add a span to that cell to span 2 cells. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    var tr = new TableRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].Length; j++)
    {
        var tc = new TableCell();

        tc.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() 
                                             { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Auto }));

        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(runTools.getRun(16, "Tahoma", new Text(data[i][j])));

        if (data[i].Length == 1)
        {
            //add a GridSpan with a value of 2 so this cell spans across 2 columns
            tc.TableCellProperties.AppendChild(new GridSpan() { Val = 2 });
            //center justify the text
            if (para.ParagraphProperties == null)
                para.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();

            para.ParagraphProperties.Justification = new Justification()
                                                        { Val = JustificationValues.Center };
        }

        tc.Append(para);

        tr.Append(tc);
    }
    table.Append(tr);
}
```

Comment: .thank you great answer. I have one more short question. To make rows have bigger width i added this tc.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa , Width="2400" })); and it is working but TableWidthUnitValues.Auto not worked. Can you make a short explanation about difference between nil,pct,auto,dxa. Which one is better to use to make rows only have larger width.

Comment: Glad I could help. To answer your second question - I recommend downloading the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) (Section 17.18.90 covers the `ST_TblWidth` value.). Essentially: 
`auto` = automatically calculated
; `dxa` = twentieths of a point (1/1440 inches)
; 'nil' - zero
; 'pct' - a percentage of the parent